# How to write Test Class for wrapperClass which contains only data members, No constructor,No methods

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

---

```
Public class restWrapper{   


public String COST_CENTER;
public String EFFECTIVE_DATE;
public String SUPERVISOR_CHANGE;
public String NEW_SUPERVISOR;
public String ORG_CHANGE;
public String NEW_ORG;
public String LOCATION_CHANGE;
public String NEW_LOCATION;
public String  NEW_DOOR;
public String JOB_CHANGE;
public String NEW_ASSIGNMENT_CATEGORY;
public String NEW_JOB;
public String APPROVER_EMAIL;
public String REQUESTER_COMMENTS;
public String NEW_GRADE;
public String POSITION_TITLE; 
public String CHANGE_PAY;
public String PAYROLL;
}
```

Comment: why does  it need a test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't write a unit test for classes like this. Only executable, non-debug, non-test, non-comment lines of code count for code coverage, so this class automatically has 100% code coverage.

Comment: Hey..@sfdcfox thank you so much for great immediate response. with out any test class, can i deploy this class right?

Comment: @purna Yes, it will deploy just fine.